# Simgrid-java. Sending instructions from Master to Worker

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, job-scheduling, simgrid

Imagine such situation that we have one scheduling system(1 Host) and, for example, 6 computers (workers) intended to perform instruction from scheduling system.
In typical situation we may use `task = new Task(name, computingSize, communicationSize)`. If we want that worker1 starts to process task we usually use `task.send(mailboxOfWorker1)`.

But what about situation when all data is stored on worker1 Host. How can we send instructions from scheduling system(`Master`) to worker1 to start to process some `task(name, compSize, commSize)`(when data of task is stored on `worker1`). Or for example such situation, how can we send instruction from scheduling system to `worker1` like that -- firstly download data from `worker2`, then (after retrieving data from `worker2`) start to execute them (on worker1)?

Comment: So you want to pass tasks one worker to the next one? Did you check the token_ring example for example?

Comment: Yes, I want that Master sends task to worker1 telling him to download data from worker2, then execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is two questions in your question.

First, you want to have worker1 to send tasks to worker2. This is perfectly legal, nothing prevents you from doing so. There is many example of this in the examples, such as `token_ring`.

Then, you want to have some extra information attached to the task. This is perfectly legal too. In Java, the best is to declare a new class derivating Task, and adding the extra fields you need. This is done in many examples too, such as `bittorrent`, `chord` or `kademlia`...